# Cannot npm install due to node-gyp: binding.gyp not found

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, node-gyp

I have been working on this all day and have tried lots of different things:

- Uninstalling node and installing latest version
- Using the `--msvs_version=` flag set to `2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2015`
- Deleting the .node-gyp folder
- Adding python path to .npmrc like so: `python=C:\Python27\python.exe`
- `npm -g install npm@next`
- Running `node-gyp rebuild` and `node-gyp configure`
- Following [Robert Kehoe's guide](https://www.robertkehoe.com/2015/03/fix-node-gyp-rebuild-error-on-windows/)

Rough times.

The package is an Electron/React app and I am running Windows 10. Console output for `npm install` is

> ```
> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\x64\Microsoft.Cpp.x64.Targets(514,5): error MSB8008: Specif
> ied platform toolset (v120) is not installed or invalid. Please make sure that a supported PlatformToolset value is sel
> ected. [C:\Users\scheinerbock\Desktop\mpstudio\node_modules\mplib\build\addon.vcxproj]
> gyp ERR! build error
> gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Users\scheinerbock\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:276:23)
> gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
> gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
> gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:215:12)
> gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.14393
> gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\scheinerbock\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
> gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\scheinerbock\Desktop\mpstudio\node_modules\mplib
> gyp ERR! node -v v6.10.0
> gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.5.0
> gyp ERR! not ok
> ```

And for `node-gyp rebuild`:

> gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: C:\Users\scheinerbock\Desktop\mpstudio) while trying to load binding.gyp

I am well out of my wheelhouse here and would appreciate any suggestions or information in addition to solutions.

Comment: Hello Ben, can you eloborate how you solved it, exact steps for a newer machine? which node version, npm version,  whats exact commands did you run to succeed it ? Thanks

Comment: @TyForHelpDude I no longer work on this project anymore, and I don't even have the computer I got things running on. So unfortunately I don't have a way of getting that info for you. Sorry

Answer (score 30):

I am using macos catalina 10.15.5 and i faced the same issues and all the above solutions didn't worked for me. I was able to resolve this by running

```
npm i -g node-gyp@latest && npm config set node_gyp "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js"
```

Hope this helps people.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Mind you... one should use the path node_gyp as determined by one's specific environment. my `node-gyp.js` was installed at `~/.nvm/versions/node/v6.17.1/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js`

Comment: fyi for others: this is fully documented [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/master/macOS_Catalina.md)

Comment: The documentation page @sam-6174 linked has since been deleted. Here’s [the permalink](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/0f1f667b737d21905e283df100a2cb639993562a/macOS_Catalina.md#node-gyp-v7).

Answer (score 16):

create a **binding.gyp** file and place it in your project root. the content of the file looks like this:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "binding",
      "sources": [ "src/binding.cc" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

A `binding.gyp` file describes the configuration to build your module, in a JSON-like format. This file gets placed in the root of your package, alongside package.json. see here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#the-bindinggyp-file

Comment: This had no effect for me on macOS High Sierra

Comment: The solution here worked after that of @Zaid Haider (https://stackoverflow.com/a/62108079/777885) on macOS Big Sur.
FYI binding.cc can just be an empty file 

Comment: I ran npm i -g node-gyp then followed along above answer and then ran node-gyp configure works without the hassle of path.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have python 2.x version installed & not 3.x
For me it worked after i installed python 2.6

Answer (score 1):

See [this thread](https://www.google.de/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjYsJjfqd3SAhXFL8AKHWr3C4EQFghGMAU&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fnodejs%2Fnode-gyp%2Fissues%2F679&usg=AFQjCNHfD8PuC5_gQiLwKBltHjL9I7obYQ&bvm=bv.149760088,d.ZGg), maybe it helps.

node-gyp uses Visual Studio for building on Windows, so I guess the issue comes from your VS installation.

Judging from this path (C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild), looks like it requires a newer version (perhaps Visual Studio 2015 where [MSBuild](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) was first introduced).

Comment: Thank you for the answer mihai. Unfortunately I did install VS2015, and I tried many other versions as well. I wound up giving up on building the project on the old computer I was using and succeeded in building on a newer machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try downgrade npm version to v6:

```bash
npm install -g npm@6
```

or downgrade node version to v12 together use [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installing-and-updating)

Ref: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/508

Answer (score 0):

Had tried so many solutions, this one seemed to work instantly for me.
Install g++ and cmake, with command 'apt install make g++', for windows I believe these have thier website for downloading.

`https://cmake.org/download/ - for make` |
`https://sourceware.org/cygwin/ - for g++` (If not search gcc on google)

I haven't tested this for windows, this worked for me with the apt command on Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `NVM` on `Windows` here's what you can do:

Create the following file at your HOME User -> `binding.gyp`

- example: `c:/users/my-user/binding.gyp`

Then this will be the content (in this case my node version is 14.21.2, but you can replace it with your current version.)

```py
{
    "targets": [{
        "target_name": "binding",
        "sources": [ "C:/ProgramData/nvm/v14.21.2" ]
    }]
}
```