# Installing the Nuxt framework in Arch Linux

Tags: css, laravel, vue.js, sass, nuxt.js

When I want to install Nuxt it with the package manager npm , it shows the following error, but I have no Yarn , Pnpm  problem with it

**npx nuxi@latest init**

Which package manager would you like to use?
npm

```
 npx nuxi@latest init frontend

✔ Which package manager would you like to use?
npm
◐ Installing dependencies...                                                    9:25:46 PM
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /../digikala-2023/frontend/node_modules/@parcel/watcher
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp info using node@21.6.1 | linux | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.6 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '/../digikala-2023/frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '/../digikala-2023/frontend/node_modules/@parcel/watcher/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '/digikala-2023/frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '/.cache/node-gyp/21.6.1/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_root_dir=/../.cache/node-gyp/21.6.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/../digikala-2023/frontend/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_lib_file=/.cache/node-gyp/21.6.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dmodule_root_dir=/../digikala-2023/frontend/node_modules/@parcel/watcher',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args 'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp: binding.gyp not found (cwd: /../digikala-2023/frontend/node_modules/@parcel/watcher) while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/../digikala-2023/frontend/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:271:18)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 6.7.4-arch1-1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/../digikala-2023/frontend/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /../digikala-2023/frontend/node_modules/@parcel/watcher
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v21.6.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.0.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /../.npm/_logs/2024-02-08T17_55_46_721Z-debug-0.log

 ERROR  Error: Command failed with exit code 1: npm install
```

### nodejs : version -> v21.6.1

### npm : version -> 10.4.0

### nuxt: version -> 3.10.1

os ArchLinux

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42638918/cannot-npm-install-due-to-node-gyp-binding-gyp-not-found might help

Comment: If i `nvm use 21.6.1` and run `npx nuxi@latest init frontend`, I don't get any errors. It uses npm 10.2.4 and I'm also on arch.